# Windows 7 and Battery Problem

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 6400/E1505 model laptop. I've recently installed Windows 7 on my computer and now my battery is not charging ? What can I do ? Is there any one who once had the same problem and then solved it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried shutting down windows and leaving the power supply on when the laptop is turned off ? Does the battery charge ?

Answer (score 1):

The O/S is completely unrelated to the battery charging. The only responsibility the O/S can have is not correctly reporting the battery charge level, which seems somewhat unlikely.

However, just in case, here are some free battery-monitoring I found (but never used):
[BatteryBar](http://osirisdevelopment.com/BatteryBar/index.html)
[SysMetrix](http://www.xymantix.com/sysmetrix/index.html)
[RightMark CPU Clock Utility (RMClock)](http://cpu.rightmark.org/products/rmclock.shtml)

If there is no problem with reporting the charge level, meaning that the battery really doesn't charge, it's either a bad battery or bad system board (ouch).

Answer (score 0):

Try a different power supply. You could borrow one, or buy a new one for about $20 online.